# How to register the cache button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have created the cache button to clear all the .json files. Its perfectly working fine in local machine. But when i uploaded in server the cache button is not working.

After uploading in server, when i click on clear cache button the message is displaying as cache(.json files) has been cleared but actually all .json files is remain as it is.

Please help me in this isuue.

below is the code

```
#region Delete Cache Functions
public bool FnDeleteCache(string directoryName)
{
    try
    {
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory + directoryName);
        di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        if (CacheAttribute() == true)
        {
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory + directoryName);
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
            {
                if (file.Name != null)
                    file.Delete();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
public bool FnDeleteCache(string directoryName, string FileName)
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory + directoryName);
    di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
    if (CacheAttribute() == true)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(rootDirectory + directoryName);
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.Name.Contains(FileName))
            {
                file.Delete();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
#endregion
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please post some code. We cannot guess what's wrong. One possibility is that your webservice doesn't have sufficient permissions to delete files.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have posted the code

Comment: Dear  xaviert, How to add permission to webservice to delete the .json files. Please help me.